# What checksums are involved/recalculated in a ZFS send/recv?

Tags: zfs, storage, checksum

I read a while back that a zfs send/recv is more immune to memory errors than a standard rsync, because it retains all of the zfs on disk checksums. I can no longer find this post, but the more I think about it, the less sense it makes, as the ZFS on disk checksums are per-disk-block, and both the disk layout (raid level) and probably block size can be different on the source and destination zpools. Does anyone know the full story here?

(I know that zfs send/recv has its *own* checksum system in addition, but what I'm asking is if the on-disk checksums are retained or recalculated).

Answer (score 1):

In ZFS the checksums are calculated on the dataset level, not pool level. So pool geometry (mirror/raidz/whatever) does not play any role here, when you send a snapshot - you effectively operate only on the dataset. You can adjust the recordsize property on the receiving size -> then the checksum would be recalculated accordingly.